# Elasticsearch aggregation taking long time

Tags: php, elasticsearch, aggregation

I am running value count aggregation and cardinal aggregation in my dataset and is using the following query.

```
GET my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [{
              "range": {
                "time": {
                  "gt": "2015-03-04 00:00:00",
                  "lt": "2015-03-04 23:59:59"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "andi.raw": "1d3d7bac8ce4c620"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "user_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "andi.raw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am running this inside a loop for various dates and at a time the timeframe will be one day and term filter have 50 terms (andi.raw aganist 50 values). One such iteration is taking around 2.5 secods to load and I have almost 50-80 iterations most of the time. So it is taking a lot of time. Is there anyway to optimize this for increase in performance ?

Answer (score 0):

Your queries look pretty intense to me. I had a similar set of queries and the multi-search API saved me a few seconds.

See [multi-search API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)